How can I see what file the pipeline has reached when running a Delta Live Tables workflow?
If I have this code where the storage_path is a string that looks something like "abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/blobs/" and this location has over 1000 parquet files (a huge amount of data in total)
@dlt.view(
    name="lmax_ns_data_view",
    comment="Raw one nanosecond 3-month snapshot from LMAX"
)

def name_of_view():
    # Set the storage path
    storage_path = "<storage_path>"

    # Set the schema
    string_columns = ["str1", "st2"]
    float_columns = ["fl1", "fl1"]
    int_32_columns = ["int32_col"]
    int_64_columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

    data_schema = StructType(
        [StructField(col, IntegerType(), True) for col in int_32_columns] + 
        [StructField(col, LongType(), True) for col in int_64_columns] + 
        [StructField(col, StringType(), True) for col in string_columns] +
        [StructField(col, DoubleType(), True) for col in float_columns]
    )

    df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
        .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet") \
        .schema(data_schema) \
        .load(storage_path) \
    
    
    return df

dlt.create_streaming_table(
    name="name_of_streaming_table",
    comment="comment",
    table_properties={
        "pipelines.autoOptimize.managed": "true",
        "quality": "bronze"
    }
)

dlt.apply_changes(
    target="name_of_streaming_table",
    source="name_of_view",
    keys=<list_of_keys>,
    sequence_by="timestamp_column",
    stored_as_scd_type=2
)

While this pipeline is running I NEED to see what file it has gotten to - I need to be able to track the progress - as you can imagine with more than 1000 files I really need to see how slow/fast it is going.
I know there's an event_log TVF which I have looked in, but it doesn't give me any info I need.
Please help!!
Also - the final destination of the data is in Unity Catalog in a Bronze table

add this to your  name_of_view() function
.withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())
More details
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/input_file_name.html

@GaneshChandrasekaran because I am using Unity Catalog i used .withColumn("FILE_NAME", col("_metadata.file_name")) instead.. HOWEVER, this still doesn't help me see what files are being processed in real time. This column is only useful when the pipeline finishes running. However I want to see in real time where readStream has got up to - any thoughts?
